# Question about cokernel of a morphism of sheaves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, schemes

Let $X$ be a scheme and let $Q$ be an $O_X$-ideal ($Q(U)$ is an ideal of $O_X(U)$ for all open $U$). 
Let $L$ be the cokernel of $0 \to Q \to O_X$.  Let $U = \operatorname{Spec}R \subseteq X$ be an affine open and $A = Q(U)$.

1. I want to prove that $L(U) = R/A$. $L$ is the sheafification of $L'$ where $L'(V) = O_X(V)/Q(V)$, but I wasn't sure  if sheafifying changes this..
2. How can I show that $(Y \cap U, O_Y) \cong \operatorname{Spec} (R/A)$?
   where $Y = \{ y \in X : 1 \notin Q_y \}$ and $O_Y$ is the sheaf on $Y$ given by restricting $L$ to $Y$.

Any clarification is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I suggest you to consult the Bosch's book of algebraic geometry.

Comment: The content of a good answer to this sort of foundational question depends on what order you learn things in. Can you clarify what book or program of study you're following and what you already know? (For example, do you already know that every closed subscheme of an affine subscheme is again affine, or is 2) going to be used to prove this fact?)

Comment: @KReiser I am following Mumford's red book.I have been trying to understand Corollary 2 II.5, and I was trying to fill in the gaps. We have established that there is a correspondence between all ideals and closed subschemes of an affine scheme. In particular, I know that every closed subscheme of an affine subscheme is again affine. However, we have not talked about quasi-coherent sheaves yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, note that we don't ever use anything outside $U$, so we might as well assume that $X=U$ here. To handle 2), we refer to a result in the section on "closed subpreschemes" (my copy has this as chapter II, section 5, theorem 3 on page 106, though my version is the "second, expanded edition" which may not have the same page numbers as the original):

> Let $X=\operatorname{Spec} R$ and let $Y\subset X$ be a closed subprescheme with inclusion $f:Y\to X$. Let $Q$ be that $O_X$-ideal defining $Y$, $A=\Gamma(X,Q)$. Then $Y$ is canonically isomorphic to $\operatorname{Spec} R/A$.

The proof of that statement may/should also give enough ammunition to resolve 1) via some of the statements about stalks, but the route using quasicoherent sheaves is preferable (in my view). The big idea is that quasicoherent sheaves on an affine scheme $\operatorname{Spec} R$ are equivalent to $R$-modules (via taking global sections, with inverse functor the "associated sheaf" construction), and their sections on standard affine opens as well as stalks have particularly nice descriptions just in terms of the ring/module data. Now, as ideal sheaves of closed subschemes are always quasicoherent and the structure sheaf is quasicoherent, we see that $L$ must be quasicoherent as well - in a short exact sequence of sheaves, if two of the three are quasicoherent, the third must be as well. So $L$ is quasicoherent sheaf, and in fact it must be the quasicoherent sheaf associated to $R/A$, which has global sections exactly $R/A$.

(In general, on a non-affine scheme, you will need to sheafify which will alter global sections of $L$. The easiest example is the ideal sheaf of two distinct points in $\Bbb P^1_k$.)

Comment: Thank you for this explanation. There is one more thing I'm still slightly not sure about, related to this...In Chapter II, Section 5, after Definition 1 he explains how sheaf of ideals determine closed subschemes. However, he doesn't assume (at least this is my understanding) $Q$ is quasi-coherent for this discussion and implies that $Y = \{ x \in X : Q_x \neq O_{x,X}\}$ is a closed subset of $X$. But I think one needs to assume $Q$ is quasi-coherent to prove this. Is this an error in the book or am I missing something?

Comment: My copy of the text reads "A *closed prescheme* of $X$ is 1) a closed set $Y\subset X$, 2) a sheaf of rings $O_Y$ so that $(Y,O_Y)$ is a prescheme, 3) a surjective homomorphism $\pi$ from $O_X$ to $O_Y$ (extended by zero). Let $Q=\ker \pi$...". So $Q$ is assumed to be the ideal sheaf of a closed subscheme, which as stated in the answer means that $Q$ must be quasicoherent.

Comment: Ah, ok. That makes sense, he is not assuming $Q$ to be any sheaf of ideals in $O_X$ when he talks about this. Thank you for the clarification.